# Calculated (calculation based on other columns)

Tags: list, calculated-column

I have 2 columns (with a yes/no choice) and want to add a third calculated column (based on column 1 and 2) that will automatically says "yes" only if both columns are set to "yes" and "no" if that is not the case.

Anybody and idea?

Thanks,
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

use this formulating `=IF(col1=TRUE,IF(col2=TRUE,"Yes","No"))`

you can read more about it [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34227.calculated-columns-for-yesno-columns-in-sharepoint.aspx)

and for Yes/No columns it would be like `=IF(col1=TRUE,IF(col2=TRUE,IF(col3=TRUE,"Yes","No")))`

Comment: Thanks That works. How does it work with multiple columns? Lets say 3 columns with yes/no? I red the article but I can't figure out how to do it..

Comment: Thanks That works. How does it work with multiple columns? Lets say 3 columns with yes/no?
I red the article but I can't figure out how to do it..

Comment: @Vin01 i updated my answer

Comment: What will be returned if column 1 is false?